# JQuery phonegap app - compound database query string

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, ios, cordova

I'm writing a quiz app using phonegap & jquery. I have a number of categories of question from which the user can select (via checkboxes), and want to build a database query to pull back the questions from the relevant categories based on their selection. The code below gives the gist of what I'm trying to achieve, but I cannot pass queryString into the executeSql() method. Is there a straightforward way of doing this that I'm missing? Thanks, Nick

```
function queryDB4(tx){
var queryString = "SELECT * FROM SBA_TABLE WHERE (";

if (toggle_cardiology == 1)
{
    queryString += "cat_cardiology = 1 AND";
}
else if (toggle_respiratory == 1)
{
    queryString += "cat_respiratory = 1"
}
// repeat for other categories

queryString += ") LIMIT 10;";
//alert(queryString);

tx.executeSql(queryString, [], querySuccess3, errorCB);
```

}

Comment: Which database are you using. I am trying to build one using phonegap and JQuery, but am concerned with the right DB to use...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that your query string is invalid. Here's one example string that your code could produce:

```
SELECT * FROM SBA_TABLE WHERE (cat_cardiology = 1 AND) LIMIT 10;
```

There are a number of problems:

- Append `1=1` (or any other statement that is always true) to handle the trailing `AND`.
- Omit the `else` clause to allow combinations of checkboxes, not just the first one that is checked.
- You need a space after `AND` to avoid producing `ANDcat_respiratory`.

Putting it together:

```
if (toggle_cardiology == 1)
{
    queryString += "cat_cardiology = 1 AND ";
}

if (toggle_respiratory == 1)
{
    queryString += "cat_respiratory = 1 AND ";
}

queryString += "1 = 1) LIMIT 10";
```

Comment: Thanks - sometimes a second pair of eyes is needed! If I were to use OR statements instead of AND, is there a nifty way to get around having the last OR stuck on the end? In this situation (i.e. SELECT * FROM SBA_TABLE WHERE cat_cardiology = 1 OR cat_respiratory = 1 OR 1=1) it looks like it just returns true due to 1=1, so the first database row is displayed regardless of the user selected categories. Or do I manually have to determine which is the last checkbox chosen, then use this info to neglect adding the last OR from the compound query?

Comment: Figured it out. For anyone who has this problem, the solution is to use a statement that returns false (i.e. SELECT * FROM SBA_TABLE WHERE cat_cardiology = 1 OR cat_respiratory = 1 OR 1=2). Thanks for your help Mark, this is a great community.